# How to record the date on column B every day, in a new line

Tags: google-sheets

I use a daily (01:00 am) script to record my daily portfolio value, calculated in sheet A, to a new sheet.

Every day the script runs, opens a new line and records the value in column A, but I have to add the date manually on column B.

The document looks like that:

```
A-----------B

$1000-----1.1.2019

$1004-----1.2.2019

... ------....

$1006-----1.5.2019
```

I couldn't find a way to automatize column B date recording. What should I add to my code?

```
function copy() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var source = ss.getRange ("calc!U12");
   var data = source.getValues();
   var ts = ss.getSheetByName("record");
   ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved without using script.  In cell B1 put your starting date.  In all of the other cells in B, drag down this formula:

```
 =IF(COUNTBLANK(A2)=0,B1+1)
```

This checks to see if the cell to the left (in A) has a value, and if it does, it will add one to the previous date.  The first date will still have to put in by hand.  You may want to make column B formatted so that the numbers appear as dates.

Comment: It doesn't work.   
The problem is my script looks for the first empty line in order to record the new data.   
If I will write anything in column B, my script will just open a new line under all my lines and record the new data there.

Comment: @YishayPeleg I am not very good at scripts, but there may be a way to check if the cell has a value, nut just a formula.  If so, you could use this because the value is only displayed if A has a value.  If not, I don't know what to do.